# Auto-resizing elements on window change (properly)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a JavaScript function that auto-resizes a div to same width/height of the window, when the window is resized.

The function is pretty basic, however I've noticed significant "paint" lag when the window is resized. In a JS fiddle, with no other elements on the page or other JavaScript, performance isn't really an issue. However in a real-world project, the lag is really annoying and something I'd like to fix.

I've iterated over a few different techniques but haven't really noticed much performance increase. Is there something I'm missing here? There must be a way to do this that's doesn't kill browser performance.

Here is the first function:

**1.**

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    var resize = document.querySelector(".resize");
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    resize.style.width = w + "px";
    resize.style.height = w + "px";
};
```

This has pretty much the worst performance out of all - http://jsfiddle.net/SY5Tn/

**2.**

```
function resizer(e,w) {
    e.style.width = w + "px";
    e.style.height = w + "px";
}

window.onresize = setInterval(function() {
    var e = document.querySelector(".resize");
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    resizer(e,w);
    }, 100);
```

this has a little better performance. Not much difference though http://jsfiddle.net/SY5Tn/2/

**3.**

```
function resizer() {
var resizeLoop;

    resizeLoop = setInterval(function() {
            var e = document.querySelector(".resize");
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            e.style.width = w + "px";
            e.style.height = w + "px";
        }, 100);

    function clear() {
        clearInterval(resizeLoop);
    }

   window.onresize = function () {
   resizeLoop();
   }
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
   clear();
   document.removeEvenetListener('mouseup');
   });

}
resizer();
```

This was the best I could come up with, although I still get an error "number is not a function"

http://jsfiddle.net/SY5Tn/3/

Is there a better way of doing this? (no Jquery please);

**P.S - I can't post this on Code Review as only have 1 rep point over there so it doesn't allow me to post multiple links.**

Comment: why are you using javascript, when you can do that by adding two simple CSS properties- width:100%; and height:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    resizeLoop = function(){
                setInterval(function() {
                var e = document.querySelector(".resize");
                var w = window.innerWidth;
                e.style.width = w + "px";
                e.style.height = w + "px";
            }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by pure CSS also using viewport units.

```
.resize {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

You can check the support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)..

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
.resize {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```